# what is the difference between hurstexp() from hurstIndex () in R

Tags: r, statistics

In  R the `PerformanceAnalytics` library I tested `HurstIndex` on SPY data for the last 20 years and got a very different result compared to using `hurstexp`<strike>onent</strike> from the `pracma` library: one suggested randomness, the other suggested very marginal persistence in the data long term, to possible mean reversion. I am unsure as to which I should rely on for the Hurst r/s statistic between 0 and 1, to imply persistence, mean reversion or randomness.`

```
hurstexp(spy_rt)  
HurstIndex(spy_rt)
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please learn that proper capitalization (and spelling) is necessary for package and function names in R.

Answer (score 0):

Without data or output from your function calls it's difficult comments specifically, but the help pages for the two functions indicate that one is the raw value and the other is the corrected value. The `help(pac=pracma, hurstexp)` help page indicates that many variants of the Hurst exponent are provided. (The Hurst Index is not limited to a range of 0-1.)

Comment: The difference between raw and corrected Hurst index does not explain the discrepancy seen here: Generate a (truly) random series with `set.seed(1001); s <- runif(1000)`, its Hurst index should be around `0.5`, shouldn't it? `pracma::hurstexp(s)` returns values in `[0.47, 0.53]`, `PerformanceAnalytics::HurstIndex(s)` gives `0.1790371`.

Comment: The data was daily stock price returns from January 2001 to 25 Feb 2020, so I think random numbers, would not help here as they would be sampled from a normal curve which the spy returns have greater kurtosis and fatter narrow tails than a normal. curve thanks anyway.

Comment: You are right the random data should be near .5 for both, one is giving an incorrect answer, or not clearly established answer.

Comment: Looking into the codes of `HurstIndex` and `hurstexp` (for the simple R/S version), the main difference is in how the intermediate term `rs` is calculated. The formula in `HurstIndex` does not take any rescaling effects into account, while `hurstexp` follows the presentation on the Wikipedia page (that is why it is called "simple"). I think 'HurstIndex' returns incorrect results.

Comment: I was inclined to go with HurstIndex as it was specifically designed for finance not engineering, or science. I have an excel VBA routine which calculates it on an old machine, I will have to check against the results from that and make a choice which to use thank you,

Comment: I just read your reply HurstIndex results are odd for the spy, 0.37 the spy is usually around .52, with downturn at the moment hurstexp is returning .52 to .49, yes I think that is correct.

Comment: @nhoj *PerformanceAnalytics* may be designed for finance, *HurstIndex* is **not**. Look at the codes: Both implement the simple R/S formula, nothing more. But *HurstIndex* misses the two lines for calculating the scaling effect. To be on the sure side, you could ask the maintainer of the *PerformanceAnalytics* package for clarification (or send a bug report).

Comment: Thanks I read wikipedia and they discussed there are numerous ways of calculating the Hurst Exponent and the rescaled range, they are not necessarily the same in the way they are calculated, as you can see clearly , I will have to refer to the papers in the bibliography of 'PerformanceAnalytics', the  'pracma implementation follows Benoit Mandelbrot the father of fractal  geometry and chaos theory's application of the implementation so that is really what I am after, but I am curios why they use a different rescaled range in 'PerformanceAnalytics'.

Comment: I do not wish to denigrate HurstIndex but the calculation by pracma is superior when reading the documentation.

Comment: After reading Mandelbrot and other sources the pracma and fractal implementations of the hurst statistics are correct according to Hurst's initial implementation, on pracma, it is the Empirical Hurst exponent from the statistics from the hurstexp() function which is most closely associated with hursts original estimate and it ties closely to the hurstSpec function from the fractal library.

Comment: The hurstIndex function from performanceAnalytics seems not to be the hurst exponent, but a measure of either  randomness, mean reversion or stability in the data, that is partially how they describe it but it does not seem to tally with any other metrics.

Comment: Incidentaly if any technical or trend traders stumble on this , in search of answers to help them, there is one simple answer, the hurst statistic does not help either at all ever. as it is historical not forward projecting, because there is persistance does not ensure its continuation for any fixed period at all.

Comment: there seems to be an error in PerformanceAnalytics Hurst calculation, I have left on the Git hub page a request to check and modify the calculation, as yet 1 week ago, from today the calculation has not changed, but these things take time, I will follow up.

Answer (score 0):

The `HurstIndex` calculation from the Performance Analytics library is wrong (or was?) that is why they differ. I left a bug report for the maintainers on the Github repo, last time I checked it had not been looked at or addressed.

The only reliable commonly used libraries for Hurst calculations are the pracma and fractal libraries. Notebly, they quoted that they adapted the `HurstIndex` statistic directly from the matlab code, somehow a bug has crept in.